# Object reference issues with static instances

Tags: c#, .net

I am curious to know that could it be possible that in the below code static Instance is not null but the MYDB class reference gets disposed by GAC and set to null ?

```
public class DA_Setting
{
    private static readonly DA_Setting instance = new DA_Setting();

    public static DA_Setting Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    db MYDB = new db();

    // Some other methods here

    private void Getname()
    {
        MYDB.GetNames(); // Sometimes this line throws null reference error on LIVE server.
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at (or show us) the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Post or Review the stacktrace. The null ref will be somewhere _inside_  `GetNames()`, not in the posted code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The GC will never, ever set something to** `null` **. Period.**

If you have a reference to an object, the GC is designed to see that you're still using the object, holding onto it by that reference, and therefore won't collect it until you're done with it.

The only way for the `MYDB` field to be `null` is if you fail to assign a value to it (and I can see you have an initializer in your code that prevents that scenario), or if you assign a value of `null` to the field at some later point in your code.

I would suggest you turn `MYDB` into a get-only property and initialize it in your class constructor:

```
private DA_Setting()
{
    this.MYDB = new db();
}

public db MYDB { get; private set; }
```

This ensures you can't set this value from outside your class and should give you a much more predictable type to work with.

Comment: If this helps solves your problem, do please mark is as the "accepted" answer to your question. If not, update your question with further information and we can try to assist you further.

Comment: The statement that "The GC will never, ever set something to null" is factually incorrect. It usually pays off checking the facts before making categoric statements. The `Target` property of the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx WeakReference class *can be* set to `null` during GC.

Comment: In the context of this discussion, the "weak reference" concept is only going to confuse the misunderstanding this developer is experiencing.

If you want to be pedantic, the `WeakReference` class checks whether the reference has been reclaimed and determines whether whether to return `null` or the assigned object - the GC does not set anything.

Answer (score 1):

The GC wouldn't collect that field if it's still reachable, and it is reachable. I guess some other object is null. Have you tried stepping into the code, maybe in the GetNames method?

Your static variable is a GC Root, that means it won't get collected as long as your Application/AppDomain is running. The field is a field of a GC root, so there should be no way for it to be collected. See here for more info about garbage collection: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/understanding-garbage-collection-in-.net/

Comment: Yes, it would be really bad if the GC would just steal your variables while your program is running, wouldn't it? I'm sure the null reference error is somewhere else, quite possibly inside the GetNames method. Try stepping into it. Or look at the stack trace that comes with the exception.

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't happen as I understand it. Static initialisers and constructors run before you access a static member - this is promised by the C# documentation. Instance initialisers run with the instance constructor, so if you're calling `DA_Setting.Instance.Getname()` there should never be a null reference there. The garbage collector is not going to randomly come along and dispose of something you've still got a reference to, and you've definitely still got a reference to this as static members don't have an end of lifecycle while the application is still running.

Have you checked what it is that's causing the null reference exception? Could it be something inside the `db` instance?

Comment: Well the log trace in position , shows that object reference is null .Since you all are saying that GC wont be disposing the references that the static Instance of a class is holding then my next step would be to run sql profiler on my LIVE server and check the parameter and value it is returning.